# Deploying NetFwTypeLib to manage the Windows Firewall

Tags: c#, deployment, assemblies, filenotfoundexception, windows-firewall

My Windows service needs to create/remove certain rules from the Windows firewall. For this I interface with `NetFwTypeLib` in `<windows>\system32\hnetcfg.dll` via COM. It works great *on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine*, but testing on another 64-bit Windows 7 machine throws the following error:

```
Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.NetFwTypeLib, 
   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
   The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have a feeling that if I embed and install the assembly with my application, I would have problems with different versions of Windows and between 32-bit and 64-bit.

How do I solve this missing assembly deployment issue?

---

**Edit:** This seems to be a [VS2010 issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/3b49656c-0f50-4989-9aed-890aac7573df/) for any target framework except 4.0. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 15):

`NetFwTypeLib` object doesn't reside in `hnetcfg.dll` on Windows 7 Ultimate. Rather, it resides in `FirewallAPI.dll` at `%system32%\FirewallAPI.dll` (eg `c:\windows\system32\FirewallAPI.dll`).

```
using NetFwTypeLib; // Add reference %SystemRoot%\System32\FirewallAPI.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

What a weird error! The best i can think of is don't rely on the `System32` version of the `DLL`, copy it into your folder and call it from there. From my knowledge, i don't think the DLL should conflict with the different bit computers, but if they do then just obtain a different DLL from a 32 bit computer and have separate downloads for `x64` and `x86`. Good luck!

EDIT: Also, i have had some trouble with programming in 3.5 or lower in `VS2010`. Try to get a version of **visual c# express 2008** and try with that (usually fixes a lot of errors with downgrading `.net` versions)

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with this same dll when working in Visual Studio 2012.

For me the fix was to manually move the `interop.NetFwTypeLib.dll` into the directory I was working from. This seemed to fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue. In this case I was moving code from one program into my company's common web utilities.

According to the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff737187(v=vs.120)

The interfaces `NetFwTypeLib` uses are also defined in Namespace:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
```

Assembly:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common (in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll)
```

Then you just need the following functions:

```
INetFwMgr iNetMgr = null;

try {
  Type tNetMgr = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr");
  iNetMgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetMgr);
}
```

Now it appears to be assembly portable without needing to do any copying of the dll, although I haven't tested it yet, the compiler didn't make any noise about it.