# Adding exception to firewall in Windows Server 2003/2008 using C#

Tags: c#, exception, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, firewall

I want to add exceptions to windows firewall in Windows Server 2003/2008.

I have written the code which works fine for Windows 7, but it doesn't work on Win server 2003/2008.

The problem is with the NetFwTypeLib (FirewallAPI.dll)

Can someone guide on the same.

Comment: If you're using VS2010 and .Net Framework < 4.0 this could be a known issue. Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296240/deploying-netfwtypelib-to-manage-the-windows-firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like its not possible.

Also from the link given in the comment by Adrian talks about same. Hence am closing the question.