# Things to consider before move to VS2010 from VS2008 C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

We have got a C# Windows application which uses devexpress controls, enterprise library and CC.net for building. We are planning to migrate VS2010 soon.

Have you come across similar situations? Are there any unforeseen issues?

Comment: Are you planning to change your target platform to .NET 4 at the same time?

Comment: Yes. And one of our other 2008 project is also going to build on .net 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still targeting .NET 3.5 then the move should be very smooth. We recently moved a very large WinForms app across and encountered a couple of minor issues:

- Some of our resx files contained serialized generic lists of our own custom types, which caused compile errors. Never got to the bottom of why this was, but we just deleted them from the resx files and set the `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]` attribute on the offending properties
- The syntax checking of XML comments is slightly stricter, meaning you could get extra warnings (and with all warnings as errors turned on this broke our build)

Answer (score 3):

If your code makes use of any of these features listed in column 1, you might need to take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We did a similar migration almost a year ago (just after Visual Studio 2010 was released). That was a little bit too early as DevExpress were not quite ready with their .NET 4 version yet. We had to run the web application in "compatibility mode" for a week or so.

There were very few issues. From what I remember (our product is half .NET and half C++):

- Some third party controls needed updating
- Some internal names crashed with new .NET 4 BCL classes.
- C++ project started to use MSBuild so that was some work up upgrade the project files.

Answer (score 1):

I faced [this](http://cooking-up-code.com/2010/08/07/vs2010-a-bug/) : on XP machine, trying to build a project referencing a COM with multiple objects inside. Specifically, i've encountered this with `INetFwMgr` - `(The type or namespace name 'INetFwMgr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Its seems that i am [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296240/deploying-netfwtypelib-to-manage-the-windows-firewall) the only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296240/deploying-netfwtypelib-to-manage-the-windows-firewall).

EDIT: [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653170/vs2010-com-interop-bug-workaround-inetfwmgr).