# Which DLL do I have to reference for NetFwTypeLib in a C# project?

Tags: c#

I'm dealing with a C# project that states

```
using NetFwTypeLib;
```

The C# compiler doesn't recognize it, saying

```
Type or Namespace name "NetFWTypeLib" was not found.
```

What do I have to do to add it to my C# project?
I see C++ examples for this, but I don't see which DLL that would be for a C# project.

Thank you!

Comment: Right-click the project -> add the DLL as a reference.

Comment: @IanKemp I don't see this DLL anywhere. Where do you find it?

Comment: maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296240/deploying-netfwtypelib-to-manage-the-windows-firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Add reference -> NetFwtypeLib

if it's not working maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296240/deploying-netfwtypelib-to-manage-the-windows-firewall) will be useful

Comment: Thank you, but the DLL name is FirewallAPI.dll, can you fix this according to the post that you linked to?

Comment: @tmighty you found it? cause mine NetFWTypeLib reference pointing to "Interop.NetFwTypeLib.dll"

Comment: @tmighty maybe VS or OS version related.

Comment: No, I didn't have the interop typelib version yet as I had never used the DLL before. The interop version is created when you fist reference the DLL. Do you want to change your answer accordingly?